# Подстановка данных из регулярного выражения в файле htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Друзья, необходимо настроить редирект в htaccess по такому образу:

Есть ссылка **kvartira-33** В htaccess мне необходимо перенаправить на /item.php?id=$1 и в место $ необходимо подставить номер 33 как в примере ссылки. Вот мой код, но он работает неверно. Помогите его отредактировать пожалуйста

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-])+([0-9\/])+$ ./item.php?id=$1
```

**Второй вопрос:**

у меня есть страница

```
/catalog/prodazha/&city=1&rion=2 и прочие гет параметры
```

Я хочу сделать правило в htaccess для того что бы редиректить такую страницу по след. адресу

./catalog.php?filtertype=1&type=5 - что то тут дописать что бы вставились гет параметры.

По сути оно должно выглядить примерно так:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/prodazha/(\?\&\=\-a-zA-Z0-9+)? ./catalog.php?filtertype=1&type=5 - что то дописать вконце что бы вставить все гет параметры которые в группе 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
^[a-zA-Z\-]+([0-9]+)$
```

еще [тыц](https://regex101.com/) очень полезный инструмент в отлаживании regex'ов

**Второй вопрос:**

Попробуйте так, должно сработать

```
^catalog\/prodazha\/\?(.*)$
```

А там где вы хотите дописать параметры

```
catalog/prodazha/?a=1&b=2&$1
```

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли вопроса. Регулярное выражение написано у меня правильно, вопрос совсем не в выражении. Я хочу сделать так что бы подставить вместо $1 только цифры на конце ссылки. Сейчас у меня в значении $1 получается либо "-" либо $2 равно "3" а я хочу получить 33, как это сделать

Comment: Или вы не поняли ответа, изменением регулярного выражения меняется группа символов, которая потом подставляется в §1

Comment: кажется я не заметил что вы взяли в скобки, я бегло просмотрел, думал вы просто убрали слеш с моего примера. Ок я отвечу ваш ответ правильным. спасибо

Comment: не подскажите еще с таким вопросом:

RewriteRule ^catalog/prodazha/(\?\&\=\-a-zA-Z0-9+)? ./catalog.php?filtertype=1&type=5$1 - тут продолжить всем урлом что был в группе 1

по подобному примеру я бы хотел что бы шел редирект на страницу с соответствующими параметрами. Как правлиьно такое сделать? Я думаю вы с моего выражения поймете что я хочу

Comment: Я не против помочь, но давайте оформим это в виде вопроса (отредактируйте текущий), код в комментариях невозможно читать и с примерами, а то не понятно некоторые моменты

Comment: отредактировал, возможно теперь будет нагляднее

Comment: Попробуйте :) неуверен до конца в правильности.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, разобрался сам. Для подстановки необходимо использовать группы в круглых скобках. Вот правильное выражение, и, соответственно, цифры — это третья группа. Чтобы их подставить, необходимо написать `$3`.

```
^([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\-){1}([0-9]+)$
```